# Change Column Width of Table for Print CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a printable table with ElectronJS for my job. I have written some code that will allow users to add new rows to tables at the press of a button. Ideally, when everything is done and laid out I want to be able to print said table.

The only problem right now is that when I try to print the table, the first column of the table is wider than I wish. When it is displaying on the screen the width is what I would like to see but when I click to print it changes the width of the column to much larger than I would like.

Here is the HTML for the table:

```js
function AddRow() {
   // Get ID for table from HTML file
   var table = document.getElementById("table");
   // Count number of columns in table
   var columnNumber = document.getElementById("table").rows[0].cells.length;
   // Add row to last row in table
   var row = document.getElementById("table").insertRow(1);
   // Create Input field in table
   var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
   newInput.placeholder = "Enter Text Here";
   newInput.classList.add("TableInput");
   // Add columns to new row matching header
   for (i = 1; i <= columnNumber; i++) {
     row.insertCell(0).appendChild(newInput);
   }
 }
```

```css
 /* Table Styling */
  #table {
    position: relative; top: 25px;
    font-family: "American Typewriter";
    border-collapse: collapse; width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px black; table-layout: fixed;
  }

  .table {
    font-family: "American Typewriter";
    border-collapse: collapse; width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
  }
  
  #table td, #table th {
    position: relative; text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  
  #table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
  
  #table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
  
  #table th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(177, 52, 235, 1.0);
    color: black;
  }

  #item {
      min-width: 150px; max-width: 200px;
  }

  .TableInput {
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th id="item">Item</th>
    <th>Ounces (Oz)</th>
    <th>Grams (g)</th>
    <th>Fluid Ounces (FOz)</th>
    <th>Milliliters (mL)</th>
    <th>Drops</th>
    <th>Completed</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The print CSS style sheet:

```css
/* Table Styling */
  #table td, #table th, #table tr
  {
    border-collapse: collapse; border: 0.5px solid black;
    width: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: x-small;
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you're printing it, you're changing the width of the table to be 100% of the view port. So I think, there lies the problem. Try to give absolute values for width in px/vh. You could also try setting individual column width (fail safe plan)

Comment: It seems you're missing the `<tr>` in the thead section. For your question you can try a fix `thead, tbody, tr { width: inherit; }` and give the `<table>` a width 100%

Comment: is your question around having different css for screen and printing?

Comment: No my question is why is there such an enormous difference in column width with the screen and with printing. I will try adding some absolute values to see if that solves the problem :)

Comment: The internet is a beautiful thing, and you're a huge part of the reason why it is Tethys0, your solution was the easy fix! Thank you!!!